# Matlab S-Function (Compiled with VS 2013) - Error while obtaining sizes (...) could not find procedure

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

When I try to run my simulation I get error from S-function:

> Error while obtaining sizes from MEX S-function 'sfunction' in 'test/S-Function'.
>   Caused by:
>   Invalid MEX-file ($PATH)\sfunction.mexw64': Could not find procedure.

My debug output:

```
'MATLAB.exe' (Win32): Loaded '($PATH)\sfunction.mexw64'. Symbols loaded.
 First-chance exception at 0x0000000077057468 (ntdll.dll) in MATLAB.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
'MATLAB.exe' (Win32): Unloaded '($PATH)\sfunction.mexw64'
'MATLAB.exe' (Win32): Loaded '($PATH)\sfunction.mexw64'. Symbols loaded.
First-chance exception at 0x0000000077057468 (ntdll.dll) in MATLAB.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
'MATLAB.exe' (Win32): Unloaded '($PATH)\sfunction.mexw64'
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MathWorks::System::SimpleException at memory location 0x000000000401F2C8.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MathWorks::System::SimpleException at memory location 0x000000000401F2C8.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MathWorks::System::SimpleException at memory location 0x000000000401F2C8.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SLSVErrorException at memory location 0x0000000004027440.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: AmbiguousNameException at memory location 0x0000000004017190.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: AmbiguousPropertyException at memory location 0x00000000040171B0.
The thread 0x1a94 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SLSVErrorException at memory location 0x000000000401B648.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SLSVErrorException at memory location 0x000000000401B648.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SLSVErrorException at memory location 0x000000000401B648.
> throw_segv_longjmp_seh_filter()
throw_segv_longjmp_seh_filter(): C++ exception
< throw_segv_longjmp_seh_filter() =EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SLSVErrorException at memory location 0x000000000401B648.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SLSVErrorException at memory location 0x000000000401B648.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SLSVErrorException at memory location 0x000000000401B648.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SLSVErrorException at memory location 0x000000000401B648.
> throw_segv_longjmp_seh_filter()
throw_segv_longjmp_seh_filter(): C++ exception
< throw_segv_longjmp_seh_filter() =EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SLSVErrorException at memory location 0x000000000401B648.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: SLSVErrorException at memory location 0x0000000004014048.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: AmbiguousNameException at memory location 0x00000000040235D0.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFCD9ADCD in MATLAB.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: AmbiguousPropertyException at memory location 0x00000000040235F0.
The thread 0x7e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I would really appreciate your input, I've been searching for solution for days

Comment: Did you properly compiled it? is There a "sfunction.mexw64" in the folder you are working on?

Comment: Yes, it is in folder. There is different error for missing sfunction. And I compiled it almost the same as MEX function. It is properly displayed in simulink with correct number of input/output ports and types :\

Comment: Well you error is `Caused by: Invalid MEX-file ($PATH)\sfunction.mexw64': Could not find procedure.`, wich seems it can not find the file

Comment: This error usually means the sfunction depends on some dynamic library and that is not available on path when the sfunction is being loaded. Use dependency analysis to find what library it is.